# Two AsyncTask in the same Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an Activity who has twoo AsyncTask. In my action bar I have twoo items that when I click call to one of this AsyncTask doing an  eventosList.clear();

to not append the new AsyncTask´s result to the list. I don´t know what is the issue that I am doing because the GetPrograma works fine the first time, GetProgramaDos works fine too but if I call another time to the button that calls GetPrograma works bad because the processDialog not disappears and the clear does´t work. Here is my code, can somebody help me? Thank you.

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    View v;

    // contacts JSONArray

    String results;
    LazyAdapterClasificacion adapter;
    String jsonStr;


     JSONArray eventos = null;
    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventosList;


    static final String TAG_ID= "id";
    static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    static final String TAG_TF= "tf";
    static final String TAG_TC= "tc";
    static final String TAG_COEF= "coef";

    String idioma;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.lista_clasificacion); 



        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // || getActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.navbar_logo));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#071607")));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        actionBar.setTitle("My Title");


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

         eventosList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


         // Calling async task to get json
         if ((new UtilsDos(MyActivity.this).isConnected())){
             new GetPrograma().execute();
         }



    }


    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private class GetPrograma extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            eventosList.clear();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);

            pDialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere...");

            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
             // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("myurl", ServiceHandler.GET);



            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                   eventos = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < eventos.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = eventos.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String pilotari = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String tf = c.getString(TAG_TF);
                        String tc = c.getString(TAG_TC);
                        String coef = c.getString(TAG_COEF);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("tf", tf);
                        contact.put("tc", tc);
                        contact.put("coef", coef);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        eventosList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;

        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

                adapter=new LazyAdapterClasificacion(MyActivity.this, eventosList, "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
                ListView milista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

                milista.setAdapter(adapter);
                pDialog.dismiss();



        }

    }





        /**
         * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
         * */

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private class GetProgramaDos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);

                pDialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere...");

                eventosList.clear();
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                 // Creating service handler class instance
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("myurldos", ServiceHandler.GET);



                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                       eventos = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < eventos.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = eventos.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String tf = c.getString(TAG_TF);
                            String tc = c.getString(TAG_TC);
                            String coef = c.getString(TAG_COEF);

                            // tmp hashmap for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            contact.put("id", id);
                            contact.put("name", name);
                            contact.put("tf", tf);
                            contact.put("tc", tc);
                            contact.put("coef", coef);


                            // adding contact to contact list
                            eventosList.add(contact);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

                return null;

            }

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */

                    adapter=new LazyAdapterClasificacion(MyActivity.this, eventosList, "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
                    ListView milista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

                    milista.setAdapter(adapter);
                    pDialog.dismiss();



            }

        }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

              getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_clasificaciones_grupo, menu);

              return true;  
        }


        /* *
         * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            menu.findItem(R.id.grupo1).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.grupo2).setVisible(true);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

         public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
                case android.R.id.home:
                   this.finish();
                   return true;

                case R.id.grupo1:
                     if ((new UtilsDos(MyActivity.this).isConnected())){
                         new GetPrograma().execute();
                     }
                case R.id.grupo2:
                     if ((new UtilsDos(MyActivity.this).isConnected())){
                         new GetProgramaDos().execute();
                     }
                    return true;

                 default:
                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                    }
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Please can you better explain what you want to happen and what happens instead? I dont understand where you are talking about.

Comment: GetPrograma AsyncTask calls url and get json data to put in a ListView, GetProgramaDos Asynctask do the same but the data is different. In the action Bar I have twoo buttons, one of this calls to GetPrograma and the other calls GetProgramaDos but it works bad because the progress Dialog not disappear and array list items not clear.

Comment: When should the progress dialog disappear? When should the list be cleared?

Comment: The list should be cleared in both cases because in my Activity I can change from one data to another every times I need. And the progress dialog should be disappear after get the data and put it in my listview

Comment: Tell when you clear the list. Until now i did not look at your code as i want to know first what should happen.

Comment: On onPreExecute of each AsyncTask eventosList.clear();

Comment: Do the asynctask run after each other or at the same time? How would you know that the first has finished before you start the second one? Do you want them to run not at the same time?

Comment: When I click a button runs one and If I want and I click another button runs the other, not at the same time.

Comment: `private ProgressDialog pDialog;`. Remove that from your activity and give every asynctask one instead.

Comment: `pDialog.dismiss();`. You have two of them in every onPostExecute. Remove the last ones.

Comment: Now works fine the progress dialog but it happens: I click the button that calls GetProgramaDos and works fine, and click later the button that calls GePrograma and the eventosList.clear(); not works fine.

Comment: `LazyAdapterClasificacion adapter;`. Remove from activity. Only declare when you need it in both onPostExecutes.

Comment: What is `ListView list;` ? Remove it. And those two InputStream's?

Comment: You can also remove eventosList from activity and give every asynctask one.

Comment: In general: use more local variables. You have too much variables which are activity variables.

Comment: ListView list and InputStream were extra code, sorry I have updated my code. I have Remove LazyAdapterClasificacion adapter from activity but still working bad, If I remove eventosList from activity it crash when I open the activity. The parenthesis are ok? because when I call GetPrograma it does the GetProgramaDos action too

Comment: Well first investigate why your app crashes. There is not much in onCreate so you can easily find the cause. You will have errors or exceptions mentioned in the logcat then. So look in the logcat. Post relevant pieces from the logcat here in a separate code block. Donot start that asynctask in onCreate.

Comment: `case R.id.grupo1:`. You forgot to have a break or return there.

Comment: But I have to start this Asynctask in On Create because GetPrograma Asynctask´s values are the defaults values that the users watch when open the activity. Later, the user can click in twoo buttons and change between GetPrograma and GetProgramaDos

Comment: For a test you do not start them in onCreate. Only when the user clicks you will start one.

Comment: Yes, thank you so so so much, the issue was the case R.id.grupo1:. I forgot to have a break or return there, thank you so so much for your help and patience